# else statement ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view, I am testing to see if certain records exist. If they do, I iterate over them and display each one. If these records do not exist, however, I want a message to be displayed. Here is the code from my view:

```
      <% if current_user.lineups %>
        <% for lineup in current_user.lineups do %>
          <li><%= link_to "#{lineup.course.cl} #{lineup.course.cn}", index_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "You have no courses", index_path %></li>
      <% end %>
```

Now, the iteration works just fine when the records exist. Whenever I create the proper records, this code works marvelously and creates a link for each record that is iterated over. However, If no records exists, nothing is displayed. The 'else' statement is completely ignored. I tried amending the 'if' stament but to no avail. I tried:

```
<% unless current_user.lineups.nil? %>
```

As well as:

```
<% if !( current_user.lineups.nil? ) %>
```

I am at my wits end here. Any and all input would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason `else` is "ignored" is that `lineups` is an empty array and empty arrays are *thruthy*. In other words, it never reaches the `else` because `if []` evaluates to `true`. Either of the answers below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your if statement

```
<% if current_user.lineups.blank? %>
   <li><%= link_to "You have no courses", index_path %></li>
<% else %>
   <% for lineup in current_user.lineups do %>
      <li><%= link_to "#{lineup.course.cl} #{lineup.course.cn}", index_path %></li>
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

it will check lineups array is empty or nil both the cases.

Answer (score 5):

Empty array is not nil, try to use `any?` or `empty?`

```
<% if current_user.lineups.any? %>
  ...
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "You have no courses", index_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
if current_user.lineups.present? # true if any records exist i.e not nil and empty
  # do if records exist
else
  # do if no records exist
end
```

present? is just not(!) of blank?

you can use `blank?`  or `present?` as per your code placement you need. 
if you use `blank?` go with @abhas answer